# OSGI Manifest in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

How do I include an OSGI Manifest in an eclipse plugin easily? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean including a manifest in Eclipse plug-ins? An Eclipse plug-in project already contains an OSGi manifest.mf, as every Eclipse plug-in is an OSGi bundle.

This manifest is already included in the binary distribution also, and you can edit it using the plugin.xml/manifest editor.